# MS ACCESS SQL Table Merge

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

Table1

```
Acct Numb Account Type Asset Mkt Val Acct Asset MV 
--------- ------------ ------------- -------------
881009201 Main Account            30           120 
881009201 Main Account            40           120 
881009201 Main Account            20           120 
881009201 Main Account            30           120 
881009203 Sub Account             50            80 
881009203 Sub Account             10            80 
881009203 Sub Account             20            80
```

Table2

```
Acct Numb Account Type Asset Mkt Val Acct Asset MV
--------- ------------ ------------- -------------
881009201 Main Account            30           200 
881009201 Main Account            40           200 
881009201 Main Account            20           200 
881009201 Main Account            30           200 
881009201 Sub Account             80           200
```

I have Table1 with the information given above. I have 2 types of accounts:

1. Main Account (ending with 01)
2. Sub Account (ending with 03)

Now, I need a table that has all of the Main Accounts as well as Sub Accounts merged together into a single Account Number, where the Account Number will be the same as its Main Account Number, but the Account Type will be `Sub Account`.

Now we have 2 more columns:

1. Asset Mkt Val
2. Acct Asset MV

In Table 1: The column `Acct Asset MV` shows the sum of Main Account (30 + 40 + 20 + 30 = 120) and `Asset Mkt Val` shows the sum of Sub Account (50 + 10 + 20 = 80).

Now in Table 2: I want to have `Acct Asset MV` contain the sum of all accounts (120 + 80 = 200) and in Sub Account the [Asset Mkt Val] should be 80.

Comment: Gord - If you're going for most edits ever, good luck with that.  However, when you edit someone's post it'd be kinda nice if you actually FIXED something and made it more gramatically correct or something.  The above post is still chock full of grammar/spelling/logic errors.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Check the edit history. I was not the first person to edit the question without giving it a complete grammar+spelling makeover. I thought that making the tables easier to read might help prevent this question from crashing and burning like its [predecessor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17299159/2144390) did.

Comment: OP - What you are requesting can't be done with the current data set.  Any grouping of data can not spearate between rows 1 and 4 in Table1, which means they will likely end up with a Cartesian product or be combined into the same record.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the data for Table2 can be derived as follows:

Start by creating a saved query named [Table1Totals]...

```
SELECT 
    Left([Acct Numb],Len([Acct Numb])-2) AS [Acct Root], 
    Right([Acct Numb],2) AS [Acct Suffix], 
    First(Table1.[Account Type]) AS [FirstOfAccount Type], 
    Sum(Table1.[Asset Mkt Val]) AS [SumOfAsset Mkt Val]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY 
    Left([Acct Numb],Len([Acct Numb])-2), 
    Right([Acct Numb],2);
```

...returning...

```
Acct Root  Acct Suffix  FirstOfAccount Type  SumOfAsset Mkt Val
---------  -----------  -------------------  ------------------
8810092    01           Main Account                        120
8810092    03           Sub Account                          80
```

Then the data for Table2 would be a UNION of the Main Account records ("*01") and a single record for each Sub Account ("*03"):

```
SELECT
    t1.[Acct Numb],
    t1.[Account Type],
    t1.[Asset Mkt Val],
    (
        SELECT SUM(t1t1.[SumOfAsset Mkt Val])
        FROM Table1Totals t1t1
        WHERE t1t1.[Acct Root]=Left(t1.[Acct Numb],Len(t1.[Acct Numb])-2)
    ) AS [Acct Asset MV]
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.[Acct Numb] LIKE "*01"
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t1t2.[Acct Root] & "01" AS [Acct Numb],
    t1t2.[FirstOfAccount Type] AS [Account Type],
    t1t2.[SumOfAsset Mkt Val] AS [Asset Mkt Val],
    (
        SELECT SUM(t1t3.[SumOfAsset Mkt Val])
        FROM Table1Totals t1t3
        WHERE t1t3.[Acct Root]=t1t2.[Acct Root]
    ) AS [Acct Asset MV]
FROM Table1Totals t1t2
WHERE t1t2.[Acct Suffix] = "03"
```

...returning...

```
Acct Numb  Account Type  Asset Mkt Val  Acct Asset MV
---------  ------------  -------------  -------------
881009201  Main Account             30            200
881009201  Main Account             40            200
881009201  Main Account             20            200
881009201  Main Account             30            200
881009201  Sub Account              80            200
```